# Concating a char array to the end of another char array (without built in functions)

Tags: c++

I have been stuck on this for a few hours now, I am required to concatenate one string to the end of another and then store the results in a third string (without the use of pre-built functions. I am having a hard time of trying to store my results into another string, I was able to get a glimpse of what I wanted however it results in an infinite loop and does not seem effective. Can anyone shine some light on this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Concat(char arr1[], char arr2[], char arr3[]);

int main(){

    char arr1[] = {"Hello how are you? \0 "};
    char arr2[] = { "The weather was cloudy today, so it rained. \0" };
    char arr3[] = { "Coffee is a great way to start the day. \0" };

    Concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
}

void Concat(char arr1[], char arr2[], char arr3[]){

    while (arr1 != '\0' && arr2 != '\0') {

        // (This outputs what a want, haveing string 2 concat to the end of the firs string) 
        // However there is no way to save it to another array or stop the infinte loop.
        //cout << arr1 << arr2 << endl; 

        arr1 + arr2 = arr3; // syntax error

    }


}
```

Comment: `arr1 + arr2` is not lvalue, so value can't be assigned to it

Comment: Looking at this I think it's apparent you need to read your lecture notes.

Comment: First of all, you need to make sure that you understand the task completely. Do you want to have the result be the concatenation of the two inputs (leaving the originals intact), or do you want to both concatenate one string onto the other (i.e. modifying one of them) and then also store that result in a third string? In any case, you have probably recently heard of the concept of dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try sth like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void concat(const char *arr1, const char *arr2, char *arr3);

int main(){
    const char *arr1("abc");
    const char *arr2("def");
    char arr3[10];

    concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
    std::cout << "arr3 is " << arr3 << std::endl;
}

void concat(const char *arr1, const char *arr2, char *arr3){

    if (arr1) {
        while(*arr1 != '\0') {
            *arr3 = *arr1;
            ++arr1; ++arr3;
        }
    }

    if (arr2) {
        while(*arr2 != '\0') {
            *arr3 = *arr2;
            ++arr2; ++arr3;
        }
    }

    *arr3 = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This really helped me understand this, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution of your problem:

```
void Concat(const char* input1, const char* input2, char* output)
{
    int i = 0;
    do {

        output[i] = *input1;
        i++;
        input1++;
    } while (*input1 != '\0');
    do {

        output[i] = *input2;
        i++;
        input2++;
    } while (*input2 != '\0');
}
```

Note: I don't check if output buffer has enough memory and other, I hope that you can edit it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to concat index by index.In the following code i first add all content of `arr1` in `arr3` then contents of `arr2` concat with `arr3`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Concat(char arr1[], char arr2[], char arr3[]);

int main(){

    char arr1[] = {"Hello how are you? \0 "};
    char arr2[] = { "The weather was cloudy today, so it rained. \0" };
    char arr3[] = { "Coffee is a great way to start the day. \0" };

    Concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
    std::cout << "arr3 is " << arr3 << std::endl;
}

void Concat(char arr1[], char arr2[], char arr3[]){

   if (arr1) {
        while(*arr1 != '\0') {
            *arr3 = *arr1;
            ++arr1; ++arr3;
        }
    }

    if (arr2) {
        while(*arr2 != '\0') {
            *arr3 = *arr2;
            ++arr2; ++arr3;
        }
    }

    *arr3 = '\0';


}
```